# Tricks to moving static objects with CSS

Tags: html, css, static

First of all, this concept started with a CodePen project here: http://codepen.io/marionebl/pen/fensm. I forked the pen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEWmwB. I changed a div to relative positioning, which made it in front of the overflow content. The **only** way to change this is to make the div static positioning.

The question: What are some tips to moving static objects? My own tips: Making a border of like 50px solid white. Or, with tags like `<p>`. You can you the whitespace tag: `&nbsp;`

Are there any other ways to position a static object?

Comment: Margins and padding are typically the best way to position elements. Using things like blank p tags adds extra markup to your page and can sometimes render different results (Depending on line-height, or styling to the p tags). I would also suggest using CSS Flexbox. It's amazing for positioning content. (Even has vertically centering) Here's a quick article I wrote with 2 helpful resources: http://www.joshuasanger.ca/so-long-floats/

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to position an object without using the position property.
Lets go over a few.

1:As Josh Sangar said in the comments Margins and paddings.
  Margins and paddings are perhaps one of the better and easier ways to position elements. Why? The main reason I believe is that unlike the position property margins and paddings will help your content react to different screen sizes without the content "disappearing" off to the side when the screen size changes.

2:Another way is to use floats. Floats are simple and is also best used with margins and padding.

There are also many obsolete ways of positioning using tables,frames etc...
You should never use these obsolete ways of the past.